# Python: retrieving a unique list

Tags: python, list

Let's say that I have a text file that looks like:

```
28
28
28
57
57
63
63
63
63
```

and so on. How do I store this in a list in my program so that it looks like [28, 57, 63, ... ] (no other ordering of the numbers is permissible!) Basically, each unique number should go into the list just once, and in the order that they are seen in the file.

Comment: If they're in sorted order, then a set will work.

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: @thefourtheye yes, `in the order that they are seen in the file`.

Comment: @alecxe - thanks for clarifying / pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to get the unique list of numbers, with the order preserved.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
    print OrderedDict().fromkeys(int(line) for line in in_file).keys()
# [28, 57, 63]
```

If the order of the elements from the file doesn't matter, you can convert each and every line to an int, put that in a `set` (which stores only unique elements) and then convert back to a list like this

```
with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
    print list(set(int(line) for line in in_file))
# [57, 28, 63]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `readlines()` method to get the elements. The result of this will be a string, so you have to convert it to `int`.

After this, you can convert it to a `set()` which will delete duplicates. And finally convert it back to a `list`:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    l = [int(e) for e in f.readlines()]
    l = list(set(l))
    print l
```

**Output:**

```
>>> [57, 28, 63]
```

You can also do this operations in one line:

```
l = list(set([int(e) for e in f.readlines()]))
```

or even, using generators (to avoid list comprehension):

```
l = list(set(int(e) for e in f.readlines()))
```

Comment: `int` will ignore the whitespaces at the endings

Comment: Unfortunately this removes the order of the elements.

Comment: If the file size is big, using `readlines` is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a great use case for a set.

```
seen = set()
result = []
for line in open('in.txt'):
    if line not in seen:
        result.append(int(line))
        seen.add(line)
```

Or with some sorting magic:

```
numbers = map(int, open('in.txt'))
print sorted(list(set(numbers)), key=lambda x: numbers.index(x))
```

Comment: but will this preserve the order in which the numbers are seen in the file?

Comment: Yes it will, since we iterate over the file line by line and append as we go.